# How does Monster Aggro work in Genshin Impact's Co-op Mode?

Tags: genshin-impact

I often play Co-op mode to clear domains, and I notice that I get targeted a lot even if I'm not the closest to the monster.

For example, yesterday I was running with Klee (me), Diluc, Keqing and Qiqi in the Level 80 Cecilia Garden Domain.
On Wave 2, two Hydro Abyss Mages spawned on both sides of the Arena. Diluc and me were hitting the closer one, and Keqing and Qiqi were hitting the further one. While I was concentrating on dodging the attacks of the closer Abyss Mage, suddenly I got hit by the further one halfway across the Arena which took out 50% of my 12,000 HP.

Why did the further Abyss Mage target me, instead of the closer Keqing and QiQi? How does the aggro work?

Comment: Good question, but how the answer would help? There is simply no concept of "tank" in this game (to focus on "agro" or to not "overagro"). You should try to avoid being hit, with few exceptions, like boosting your damage. Watch your surroundings, move camera further (it constantly resets or bugs), use environment, make sure to have healer in your group for tough encounters or just use the food to heal.

Comment: @Sinatr While there are no aggro generating skills (yet?), there are characters with shields and counters that can and want to take hits to increase their damage output, such as Beidou and Zhongli. These characters might want to intentionally facetank enemies so teammates would not be hit. Also, some groups may not want to run healers for faster dps and hence clear times.

Comment: Can you confirm that you being hit is not the result of Keqing/Qiqi dodging the attack and you getting hit by it instead?